# Cannot find module @angular/common/http even I have Angular 4.4.*

Tags: angularjs, httpclient, ionic3

I have updated my angular packages versions as below.

[image]

I want to use `import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';` but I module could not found and even for httpClient also.

See below.

[image]

**How could I fix this?**

Comment: did you try to restart your IDE?

Comment: @smnbbrv I restated my computer, but still does not work.

Comment: maybe a stupid question but did you run `npm update`?

Comment: @smnbbrv off course, I install npm update package and then run the `ncu -u`. All the packages updated automatically.

Comment: then just go to those file and check whether the HttpClientModule is exported there...

Comment: @smnbbrv, I checked. It is not existed `http` folder under `@angular/common`. How could I get it there?

Comment: that is weird. Either angular has exported nothing or the version you put in is not existing or it was not installed. I would try to remove node_modules and install again - if it does not really help then look at other two options above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I got the solution.

Actually, I don't know the main reason but the path of `http` under `@angular/common` is different in my case.

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/@angular/common/http';
```

Then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your  `module.ts`

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

It should work

Comment: It is existed in module.ts but nothing. Please see the picture I added up.

Answer (score 0):

No the actual issue is with the **[`stackblitz`](http://h%20this%20is%20a%20known%20bug%20with%20type%20definitions%20in%20sub-packages,%20we%20have%20a%20fix%20coming%20for%20it%20soon.%20That%20code%20will%20actually%20work%20in%20the%20preview%20btw,%20it's%20just%20the%20red%20underline%20is%20incorrect!)** itself,

> this is a known bug with type definitions in sub-packages, we have a
>   fix coming for it soon. That code will actually work in the preview
>   btw, it's just the red underline is incorrect!